# Umbraco after installing Ucommerce getting Keyword not supported: 'flush interval' error

Tags: umbraco

Server Error in '/' Application.
Keyword not supported: 'flush interval'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'flush interval'.
Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'flush interval'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5764228
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +27
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential) +26
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +11
   UCommerce.Installer.RuntimeVersionChecker.GetUCommerceDatabaseAssemblyVersion() +133
   UCommerce.Installer.UpdateService.UpdateIsNeeded() +30
   UCommerce.Umbraco7.Installer.Installer.InstallInternal() +498
   UCommerce.Umbraco7.Installer.Installer.PreStart(Object sender, EventArgs e) +99`enter code here`
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking :)

Are you using SQL CE? 
- uCommerce doesn't support CE, therefore you need to use Sql express or Sql Server to install uCommerce.

uCommerce actually has an community, which will help you with uCommerce questions. 
http://eureka.ucommerce.net/ -Normally, we don't check in here that often. So you will get an faster answer on Eureka.

Let me know if you need any extra help to this.

Regards
Mads